# "set_correct " Class is applied to the all the elements. why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my javascript quiz page. I'm facing the issue set_correct  class is applied to the all elements. But I want this class should be apply to only the correct answer. "set_wrong" class also should be apply to the wrong answer.  please look at my code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="button_port">
<input type="button"  id="btnid" class="pevcls" value="Previous Question" onclick="Prevfn()">
<input type="button" id="btnidnt" class="nextcls" value="Next Question" onclick="Nextfn()">
</div>
<div class="content_box">
<div id="question">
</div>
<div id="answer_button">
</div>
</div>
</div>

var i=1;
var questionpos=document.querySelector(".content_box");
var getquestion=document.getElementById("question");
var answersbutton=document.getElementById("answer_button");


function Prevfn()
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("btnid").disabled=true;
        alert("Dont have the previous one");
        document.getElementById("btnidnt").disabled=false;
    }
    else{
        i--;
        setquestion();
    }
    
}
function Nextfn()
{
    
    if(i==5)
    {
        var ind=document.getElementById("btnidnt").disabled=true;
        
        document.getElementById("btnid").disabled=false;
        alert("Dont have next content");
        
    }
    else{
    i++;
    setquestion();
    }
    
   
}
var allAnswerButtons = [];

function setquestion(question)
{
var questionsvari=questions[i].question;
getquestion.innerHTML=questions[i].question;
allAnswerButtons.forEach(abutton => abutton.remove());
allAnswerButtons = [];
questions[i].Answers.forEach(answer=>
    {
        
        const button=document.createElement("button");
        button.classList.add('Ans_btn');
        
        button.innerText=answer.text;;
        if(answer.correct)
        {
        button.dataset.correct=answer.correct;  
        }
        
        button.addEventListener('click', selectanswer);
        answersbutton.appendChild(button);
        allAnswerButtons.push(button)
        
        
    }
    )
    
}
    function selectanswer(e)
    {
        var sal_answer=e.target;
        var tof_value=sal_answer.dataset.correct;
        
        Array.from(answersbutton.children).forEach(function(button)
        {
         
          setStatusClass(button,tof_value);
        
        }
        )
    }
    
    function setStatusClass(element,correct)
        
    {
        console.log(element);
        if(correct=="true")
        {
        
        clearstatusclass(element);
        element.classList.add('set_correct');   
        }
        else
        {
        element.classList.add('set_false'); 
        }
    }
    

    function clearstatusclass(element)
    {
        element.classList.remove('set_correct');
        element.classList.remove('set_false');  
    }

const questions=[
{
    question:"How many factors do a prime number have?",
    Answers:[{text:'1 and the number itself',correct:'true'},{text:'2 and the 4',correct:'false'},{text:'3 and 6',correct:'false'},{text:'4 and 8',correct:'false'}]
},
{
    question:"What type of term 2x+7y is?",
    Answers:[{text:'234',correct:'true'},{text:'Binomial',correct:'false'},{text:'132',correct:'false'},{text:'222',correct:'false'}]
},
{
    question:"What is the percentage of 2:5?",
    Answers:[{text:'JavaScript',correct:'false'},{text:'40%',correct:'true'},{text:'JavaSql',correct:'false'}]
},
{
    question:"Which food contains lactobacillus?",
    Answers:[{text:'Curd',correct:'true'},{text:'Jojeshe',correct:'false'},{text:'JavaSql',correct:'false'},{text:'JavaSql',correct:'false'}]
},
{
    question:"What is the national game of Bangladesh?",
    Answers:[{text:'JavaScript',correct:'false'},{text:'Jojeshe',correct:'false'},{text:'Kabaddi',correct:'true'}]
},
{
    question:"What is the national game of Bangladesh?",
    Answers:[{text:'JavaScript',correct:'false'},{text:'Jojeshe',correct:'false'},{text:'Kabaddi',correct:'true'}]
}
];
```

My full code is below
https://codepen.io/pavisaran/pen/wvgQaew

Anyone please tell me where Im doing my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the answer, you go through all the options (buttons) instead of setting for one.

```
function selectanswer(e)
{
    var sal_answer=e.target;
    var tof_value=sal_answer.dataset.correct;
        
    Array.from(answersbutton.children).forEach(function(button)
    {
         
    setStatusClass(button,tof_value);
        
    }
    )
}
```

Change `button.addEventListener('click', selectanswer);` in `setquestion` to `button.addEventListener('click', (e) => selectanswer(e, button));`

And fix selectanswer

```
function selectanswer(e, button)
{
    var sal_answer=e.target;
    var tof_value=sal_answer.dataset.correct;
             
    setStatusClass(button,tof_value);
}
```